# How to do INSERT SELECT INTO in Java using PrepareStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to do an INSERT INTO SELECT which are inserting into in 1 table by selecting specific data in columns from 2 tables. The thing is, it will involve with user input from JTextField as well. I have searched for many solutions but still got an error and I just dunno what else to do. I'm using Java as PL and Oracle as DB. This is what I have got so far :

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","ghost","slayer");

stmt = con.createStatement();

String sbjC = sbjCode.getText(); //textfield for subjectCode
String sbjN = sbjName.getText(); //textfield for subjectName
String matricsno = textstudentid.getText(); //textfield for matrics number
String sbjG = sbjGrade.getText(); //textfield for subjectGrade (not gonna be use in db, just for comparison)

String sql1 = "INSERT INTO transferred (subjectCode,subjectName,credit,prequisite,matricsNo) "
    + "SELECT b.subjectCode,b.subjectName,b.credit,b.prequisite,s.matricsNo "
    + "FROM bitm b, student s "
    + "WHERE b.subjectCode = '"+sbjC+"' AND b.subjectName = '"+sbjN+"' AND s.matricsNo = '"+matricsno+"'";

/* table Transferred has 5 column which are subjectCode,subjectName,credit,prequisite,matricsNo [matricsno as FK]
 * table bitm has 5 column [subjectCode as PK]
 * table student has 6 column [matricsno as PK]
 */

ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

ps.setString(1, sbjC);
ps.setString(2, sbjN);
ps.setString(3, "SELECT credit FROM bitm WHERE subjectCode = '"+sbjC+"' AND subjectName = '"+sbjN+"'");
ps.setString(4, "SELECT prequisite FROM bitm WHERE subjectCode = '"+sbjC+"' AND subjectName = '"+sbjN+"'");
ps.setString(5, "SELECT matricsno FROM student WHERE matricsno = '"+matricsno+"'");

ps.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

The only error I have got after executing and insert all data needed into JTextField is **java.sql.SQLException : Invalid column index**.

The SQL statement has been test in SQL Developer and succeed. Just I'm bit confused on how to do it on Java.
Thank you for all of your response and time.
I'm a newbie in Java.

Comment: which line creates that error? One of the `.setString` ones? Where are the corresponding `?` that you set dynamically with those lines? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Your parameters are completely off.  You're trying to set `select` queries as parameters?  I think you need to take a step back and learn the basics of how prepared statements work.

Comment: Your query has not parameters. You need to put `?` into the SQL string instead of the actual parameters. You also can **not** use a `select` statement as a parameter string.

Comment: `ps.setString(1, sbjC);
ps.setString(2, sbjN);
ps.setString(3, "SELECT credit FROM bitm WHERE subjectCode = '"+sbjC+"' AND subjectName = '"+sbjN+"'");
ps.setString(4, "SELECT prequisite FROM bitm WHERE subjectCode = '"+sbjC+"' AND subjectName = '"+sbjN+"'");
ps.setString(5, "SELECT matricsno FROM student WHERE matricsno = '"+matricsno+"'");` 
is weird

Comment: I have tried replace it with ? and the error I get is **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound**

Comment: ...AND b.subjectName = **'"+sbjN+"'** AND s.matricsNo = **'"+matricsno+"'** , well I get the value directly from JTextField because they are both from 2 different tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For  PreparedStatement, you'd code ? Into the sql and later replace that with values.

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO transferred (subjectCode,subjectName,credit,prequisite,matricsNo) "
                    + "SELECT b.subjectCode,b.subjectName,b.credit,b.prequisite,s.matricsNo "
                    + "FROM bitm b, student s "
                    + "WHERE b.subjectCode = ?  AND b.subjectName = ? AND s.matricsNo = ? ";


            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

            ps.setString(1, sbjC);
            ps.setString(2, sbjN);
            ps.setString(3,matricsno);

ps.executeUpdate ();
```

This should do it.

Your error came from giving parameters (setString...) without matching ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have replace it and it generate error :
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: Can you update question with current code? Three questionmarks and parameter index 1 to 3 should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've update the code and also the error I've got as well.

Comment: Check last line!! Not executeUpdate (sql1) but only executeUpdate ();

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works! Thank you so much. The data has been successfully insert into the db. :D

Comment: Yes and I've accepted it. Thank you again for your time. But I can't upvote it because lack of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you absolutely misunderstood what the preparedStatemet does.
You have to write ? -s into the query and the preparedSatement is going to replace it on a typed way:

```
 String sql1 = "INSERT INTO transferred (subjectCode,subjectName,credit,prequisite,matricsNo) "
                    + "SELECT b.subjectCode,b.subjectName,b.credit,b.prequisite,s.matricsNo "
                    + "FROM bitm b, student s "
                    + "WHERE b.subjectCode = ? AND b.subjectName = ? AND s.matricsNo = ?";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ps.setString(1, sbjC);
            ps.setString(2, sbjN);
            ps.setString(3, matNo);
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It is a wrong way to try to add a whole query as a replacement:
ps.setString(5, "SELECT matricsno FROM student WHERE matricsno = '"+matricsno+"'");

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I'll put comment on the changes that I have made to the code and make it work:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","aza","jaiza");

stmt = con.createStatement();

String sbjC = sbjCode.getText();
String sbjN = sbjName.getText();
String matricsno = textstudentid.getText();
String sbjG = sbjGrade.getText();

String sql1 = "INSERT INTO transferred (subjectCode,subjectName,credit,prequisite,matricsNo) "
        + "SELECT b.subjectCode,b.subjectName,b.credit,b.prequisite,s.matricsNo "
        + "FROM bitm b, student s "
        + "WHERE b.subjectCode = ? AND b.subjectName = ? AND s.matricsNo = ?"; // from textfield to ?

ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

ps.setString(1, sbjC);
ps.setString(2, sbjN);
ps.setString(3, matricsno);

//from all the SELECT statement to just 3 user-input-from-textfield column

ps.executeUpdate(); // remove the sql1 in ps.executeUpdate(sql1);
```