# how can I copy a row with a single value change?

Tags: java, clickhouse

Imagine a table having a row with some values. I want to insert a new row in this table, so that it has the same values for all columns except one.

I can do so by getting the values from the row I already have and then inserting a new one, like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (id == ?);";

try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    statement.setLong(1, some);

    try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            long someValue1 = rs.getLong("someValue1");
            long someValue2 = rs.getLong("someValue2");
            String someValue3 = rs.getString("someValue3");
            long someValue4 = rs.getLong("someValue4");
            String someValue5 = rs.getString("someValue5");

            insert(someValue1, someValue2, someValue3, someValue4, someValue5, changedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there are ways to optimize this solution

Comment: How would you like to optimize?

Comment: Only idea I have is that you could combine the insert and select. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441419/how-to-do-insert-select-into-in-java-using-preparestatement for something similar)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `resultSet` returned by your query and then commit it as a new row like this:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
    if (rs.next()) {
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        int newAge = rs.getInt("age") + 5;
        rs.updateDouble( "age", newAge );
        rs.updateRow();
        rs.insertRow();
    }
} catch (SQLException) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INSERT/SELECT statement and do this with a single hit to the database. You'll only need to pass in

1. The ID of the row you are copying
2. The value that is different

The rest of the values can then be copied from an existing row

```java
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
   "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3) " +
   "SELECT t.VALUE_1, t.VALUE_2, ? " +
   "FROM MY_TABLE t " +
   "WHERE t.ID = ?"
);
ps.setString(1, value3);
ps.setLong(2, id);
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
if (result != 1) {
   throw new Exception("Inserted " + result + " rows (expected 1)");
}
```